# Save Recycle Bin view settings - Win 10

Tags: windows-10, sorting, default-settings, recycle-bin

I want to always display deleted items sorted by `Date Deleted` (I am using detailed view).  But whenever I open Recycle Bin it auto sorts by `Name`.  When I sort it by `Date Deleted` and close the window, then reopen it, it reverts back to sorting by `Name`.  I tried Ctrl+close, F5, Shift+close..  Nothing works to keep the saves view settings!  Any suggestions? Or where to edit the folder settings to save that? Or edit the "folder type" to make it "General" to test? Or an option to reset the folder settings?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Are you using the Detailed view?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, detailed view.

Comment: I would suggest to do `chkdsk` and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I already do that now and then (I'll try again now), but the issue has been persistent for months.  Is there a way to reset folder view settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOt sure what **FixWin** does, but based on your description, you'd hit the max of 5000 saved views and the following registry keys needed to be deleted:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

So I'm assumig it did thtat.

When the view is set to your liking, with the folder still open:

- **View** Ribbon -> `Folder Options ->` Change folder and search optionns `-> **View** tab -> **`Apply to Folders`**

This will save your preferred view as the custom default view for the Recycle Bin's unique *FolderTypeID* ( *`{D6D9E004-CD87-442B-9D57-5E0AEB4F6F72}`* ) uder the registry key:

```
    HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods to reset the Recycle Bin:

**Method 1 - Remove the folder**

- Open an elevated Command Prompt window
- Run the following command (replace `C:` if required):

  ```
    rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.bin
  ```
- Reboot to recreate a new Recycle Bin.

**Method 2 : Use FixWin**

- Download
  [FixWin10.zip](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fixwin-for-windows-10)
- Unzip the archive and launch the `.exe` file
- Click to select the "Additional Fixes" section
- Choose the "Quick fixes" tab
- Press the "Reset Recycle Bin" button
- Wait for the fix to run and then reboot.

Comment: I tried the FixWin, worked, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately after a couple of restarts same issue happened. and even recreating a new Recycle Bin didn't work.